# I am unsure why it cannot read property 'id' even though the code was working yesterday

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'd like help knowing why `id` is not defined and how I can fix it. I am really stuck on this as the command was working perfectly fine yesterday. Is there an update I'm not aware of? Is my coding just straight up wrong?

Here's my code:

```js
const { Permissions } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: 'test',
    description: "A test command",
    execute(client, message, args) {
        const member = message.mentions.users.first();
        const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
        const roleOne = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Role Name 1")
        const roleTwo = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Role Name 2")

        if (!message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Role Name 1")) {

            message.guild.roles.create({
                data: {
                    name: "Role Name 1",
                    color: "#FF8CC5",
                    permissions: [Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_MESSAGES]
                }
            });
        }

        if (!memberTarget.roles.cache.has(roleOne.id)) {

            if (!memberTarget.roles.cache.has(roleTwo.id)) {
                message.channel.send("This member doesn't have either role!")
            } else {
                message.channel.send("This member has Role Two")
            }

        } else {
            message.channel.send("This member has Role One")
        }
    }
}
```

And the exact error is:

const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: This shows that there are no user mentions. Make sure you are mentioning a member.

Comment: I see, however, I'd like to ask another thing. Yesterday, my main command using this was working completely fine, and it allowed me to type the command without mentioning a player causing it to return a message saying that you need to mention someone. But now all of a sudden, I'm forced to mention someone else an error pops up. I'm really confused why this is suddenly happening. I'm not sure if I slightly changed up my command but I would really like to know, if you know, how I could make this possible

Comment: You likely changed your code or something. To check whether a user was mentioned, you can simply check that `member` is not null/undefined before setting `memberTarget`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this before declaring `membertarget`

```
if (!message.mentions.members.first()) return message.reply("Please mention a user")
```

EDIT: `if (!member) return message.reply("Mention a user first")`